# Create a temporary file on the server of my project

Tags: php

Is there a way to create a temporary file on the server of my project. It is supposed to save a picture i don't need permanently.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: http://php.net/tmpfile ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`tmpfile()`](http://php.net/tmpfile)

Code from the manual page:

```
<?php
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, "writing to tempfile");
fseek($temp, 0);
echo fread($temp, 1024);
fclose($temp); // this removes the file
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [tempnam](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php) or [tmpfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) - Your choice.